# dig domain ANY return refuse connection to port 53

Tags: dns, dig, kal

I tried to run the below dig command:
`dig www.google.com ANY 
 dig google.com ANY`
 
but i always got the respone 

`;; Connection to 172.16.137.2#53(172.16.137.2) for www.google.com failed: connection refused.`
 
I tried many other domains but nothing changed.
What would be the possible issue ?

Comment: You have 2 problems: 1) do not use ANY, it will soon become deprecated and in any(!) case it does not do what you think it does and 2) when using `dig` always specify exactly which nameserver you are querying for the information with the `@` option (here you got a reply from `172.16.137.2` is it the one you wanted? This one does not want to answer you because it does not even run a nameserver here). But what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Some DNS servers just refuse to answer ANY queries (including some resolvers).  Still, "connection refused" would be a bad way of doing that, so it might be some other problem...

Comment: Yes, some servers do implement it in some way :-)